# custom Indic keyboard transliteration : how to

Tags: python, keyboard, transliteration, indic

Here's the [thing](https://github.com/amrutnrp/Odia_Keyboard_Layout__Disguiser).
You type <KEY> and <MAP> gets printed.
where <KEY> is a character in English keyboard, <MAP> is a character in (Odia) Indic language.

```
<KEY> -> <MAP>
A-> ଅ kh->ଖ  
jif -> ଜୀ   bharq -> ଭାରତ  ahmerika-> ଆମେରିକା   
prhqhibif -> ପୃଥିବୀ
```

It's not 1->1 mapping, it's a custom algo. I have done it in tkinter textbox (python). But, it doesn't feel native. If you type outside the textbox-> it'll print <KEY>(English).

I'm aiming for printing <MAP> instead of printing the English character- regardless which application you're on. (something like Akruti Software)

How to do it in a way that feels native and seamless. Any ideas/pointers ?

Comment: Actually, many indic typing tools do the same thing.  They read the keypress from low level windows drivers and modify what needs to be printed.  unfortunately they are not open source. I'll probably have to make this program from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/amrutnrp/4f537eb5327a145a05d4ec2be81ccc31) is an code snip that maps out key 'a' to a unicode value.
[Here](https://github.com/amrutnrp/Odia-Fasttype-windows)'s my personal project on Odia Transliteration

Implemented in C++. (to make it universal and fast).